# Puzzling and Social Networks

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if there is any Puzzling.SE related group/page in the most famous social networks (Facebook, Twitter, ...).

In Facebook, for example, I've found this:
http://www.facebook.com/stackexchange/
and this:
http://www.facebook.com/officialstackoverflow

Though, I haven't found anything specific about Puzzling.SE.
Is it because we're still in Beta? If so, I think that social networks could be a great opportunity to make the community grow. What do you think about?

Comment: Do you mean Puzzling **.SE** related or just puzzling-related in general?

Comment: @randal'thor I mean Puzzling.SE, I will clarify it in the OP asap